# How do I securely add an api key to a dockerized Shiny App?

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I have an R shiny app, and I want to deploy it in a docker container.

At the moment, the Shiny app retrieves an `api_key` from my environment, and uses it to retrieve data.

In order to make this `api_key` available to Shiny within the container, it looks like I have to save it within `/home/shiny/.Renviron`.
This means that people who receive the container can explore the filesystem and find the `api_key`.

I'm wondering if there's any way around this; is there any way to make the `api_key` available to the shiny app, but not to people who receive the container image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure environment variable for the container:

```
docker run -d \
  -e API_KEY=<api-key> \
  ...
  shiny-app-image
```

And use it in R:

```
Sys.getenv("API_KEY")
```

So variable `API_KEY` will be defined on the container level, not in the Docker image.

Comment: Is this the equivalent of defining `ENV` in the Docerfile? If so, this doesn't solve my problem because Shiny Server doesn't seem to be able to access environment variables that aren't specified through `.Renviron`. I noticed now that I failed to mention Shiny Server in my question.